# Remote debugging in Android

Tags: adb, remote-debugging, portforwarding

I want to debug android app running on a device which is USB-attached to some remote machine [call Server here] in network from my local system/eclipse [say Client].

I think it's achievable using port forwarding.

I tried adb forward command following way:

```
in Server: adb forward tcp:6037 tcp:5037
in Client: adb forward tcp:5037 tcp:<remote-host>:6037
```

but when I fire command in Client, I get "error: cannot rebind smartsocket" or in some systems "Internal error."

Any sort of idea what wrong I'm doing?